# Postgres logs out ldap connection settings including password

Tags: ldap, postgresql

I'm trying to configure PostgreSQL instance to use LDAP server for authentication. It's working fine. The only thing I don't like are the logs. In case if login does not succeed Postgres logs out all the ldap connection settings including the bindpasswd:

```
LOG:  LDAP login failed for user "uid=<user>" on server "<ldap-server>:389": Invalid credentials
FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "<user>"
DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 93: "host all all all ldap ldapserver="<ldap-server>"  ldapbasedn="<base-dn>" ldapbinddn="<binddn>" ldapbindpasswd="<PASSWORD>"
```

Is there the way to disable the DETAIL logging?

Comment: Have you changed the default logging level? If postgresql is logging passwords with the default configuration, should fill a bug ticket to them.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `log_error_verbosity = TERSE` removes DETAIL from the log

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-logging.html